# How to find a session from MongoDB collection using Express and MongoStore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I am implementing a session store using Node/Express/Mongo. My problem is that I cannot retrieve any sessions from my `sessions` collection, so I am unable to determine whether a user has already logged in.

I am using MongoSkin, MongoStore, and mongo-connect, although I don't mind using Mongoose and other tools.

Here is my debug output:

```
// Check whether the current user has a session.
// If so, adds "currentUser" to the request.
// Else, redirect to the login page.
function loadUser(req, res, next) {
    console.log("loadUser: checking loadUser...");
    var db = req.db;
    console.log("current req.session.token:");
    console.log(req.session.token);
    console.log("current req.session:");
    console.log(req.session);
    if (req.session.token) {
        // Look up the session id in the database 'sessions' collection.
        db.collection('sessions').findOne({token : req.session.token}, function(err, user) {
            console.log("found user by looking up token:");
            console.log(user);
            if (user) {
                req.currentUser = user;
                next();
            } else {
                console.log("token not in 'sessions', redirecting...");
                res.redirect('/login/webapp_login.html');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("no token, redirecting...");
        res.redirect('/login/webapp_login.html');
    }
}
```

And here is the console output:

```
loadUser: checking loadUser...
current req.session._id:
53acb8e1b7b297dc29681def
current req.session:
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  isLogged: 21,
  username: 'sessiontest1',
  token: '57a6dfe0bea9150bd4e2d1f76974e88b',
}
found user by looking up token:
null
token not in 'sessions', redirecting...
```

Along with:

```
        db.collection('sessions').find(req.session._id, function(user) {
```

I also tried:

```
db.collection('sessions').findOne({session:{token:req.session.token}}, function(err, user) {
```

but I still get `null` and the function redirects. Am I missing something? Any suggestions would be helpful. I am using MongoSkin, although I am open to solutions in Mongoose as well.

Additionally, I know that my database is configured correctly because I checked the command line:

```
> db.sessions.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : "vnftBGNFVQ3S4lHiIB_omOxWDu01kFuH",
        "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":t
rue,\"path\":\"/\"},\"isLogged\":6}",
        "expires" : ISODate("2014-07-09T03:44:54.863Z")
}
{
        "_id" : "-AMKc_kIzOOAn_eQJ6RJpvTgWoargLaJ",
        "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":t
rue,\"path\":\"/\"},\"isLogged\":20,\"username\":\"sessiontest1\",\"token\":\"57a6dfe0bea
9150bd4e2d1f76974e88b\"}",
        "expires" : ISODate("2014-07-11T06:35:14.835Z")
}
```

What is going wrong, and why can't I retrieve a session from my `sessions` collection?

**Update**
running

db.collection('sessions').find({"session" : /./}, function(err, user) {

gives me an output, so I believe the problem is matching a record with a field within the session field's string. The `session` field, shown in the database output above, is problematic because it one long string and not a nested JSON.

Also, my `sessions` records are inserted automatically after adding this to my `app.js`:

```
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 's3cretc0de',      
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: mongoUrl      
    }, function () {
        console.log("db session connection open");
    })
}));
```

And I added the `token` and `username` fields within my router, shown below:

```
router.get('/verify', function(req, res) {
    req.session.username = username;
    req.session.token = req.query.token;
}
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use MongoStore for storing your session data you don't need to query the MongoDB directly. The module does everything for you.

You can just use `req.session` to get your session data.

So in your routes you can do something like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // check if the username is set in the session
  if (!req.session.username) {
    // redirect it to login page
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    // do something
  }
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    // you would check check the username & password here
    // if (username == '...' /&& password ...)

    // set the username in the session session 
    req.session.username = username; 
});
```

Comment: That was it, thank you. Just curious, since I thought MongoSkin was a wrapper for MongoDB: does MongoSkin handle cursors as well? Would the appropriate handling of a cursor in MongoSkin be to convert the result to an array before the callback? For example, if I needed many records, would I use: `db.collection('myCollection').find({"key":req.session.someValue},).toArray(function(err, items) {`?

Comment: @Lucas MongoSkin actually wraps some of the common functions and returns promises (to avoid callback hell). If you're using MongoSkin, you can use it like that to handle multiple items. `toArray` method in your example is actually invoked on the cursor (SkinCursor object actually).

Comment: I just realized that this answer does not work. I had other records in my `sessions` collection that coincidentally matched the `{"_id": req.session._id}` predicate. I also tried your original answer, `{"session._id":req.session._id}` but it does not work either. When I use the predicates `{"_id": /./}` or `{"session": /./}`, I always get a match. I think this is due to the `session` field not being nested JSON but a literal string. Do you have any suggestions? Is there a way to select for the fields inside the `session` field? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ChristianP if we need a list of all sessions and delete/destroy a specific one. How can we do that with MongoStore